# Is it possile to deploy each module separately in GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Is it possible to deploy each module separately to Google App Engine on Java Runtime.
If it is possible please let me know how to do that.
Please point me towards some resources that can help me.
I just followed the process [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/webtoolsplatform)

help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can upload specific module by pointing appcfg to the module's directory: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/#Java_Uploading_modules

Tools that build on top on appcfg should have this option too.

Comment: Yes, it's certainly possible using `mvn` and `gcloud` too.

Comment: Thanks Gabriel. But how can I do it from Eclipse without using maven.

Comment: See the above link for use with appcfg, not maven. I haven't used Eclipse's plugin for a while, but I imagine that if you have an Eclipse project for each GAE module, using the plugin's update command on the project would update the module.